# how to search endpoint from the server using Star Wars SWAPI API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, express

I am trying to add a search query to the server-side endpoint, which calls swapi - the Star Wars API `https://swapi.co/` and lists people by name.

Here's what the fetch call to the backend in App.js looks like (I am using reactJS framework for that):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: [],
    }
  }

    searchPersonByName = (event) => {
    fetch('/people/?search='+ event.target.value)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        //let searchResult = JSON.parse(responseBody).results;
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ searchResult: response.results });
      })
  }
render() {
    return (
      <div className="pageStyle">
        <div className="searchBar">
          <input type="text"
            placeholder="search for a person"
            onChange={this.searchPersonByName}>
          </input>
          {Object.keys(this.state.searchResult).map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <span>{this.state.searchResult[item].name}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

on the backend:

```
    //Dependencies
    const swapi = require('swapi-node');
    const express = require('express'); //express server
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static('public'))

    //Search people endpoint
    //format of the search string:
    // https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=
    app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
    let query = req.query.search;
    console.log(query);
    swapi.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=' + query).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.results);
        let results = result.results;
        res.send({ results });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});
//server listening on specified port
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on port 4000!'))
```

Right now the search query return the people from the first page only. What is missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a search term to the backend with your `fetch` request.

If you really want to search for every change in the input field, you could use the `event.target.value` as search term.

```
searchPersonByName = event => {
  fetch(`/people?search=${event.target.value}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ searchResult: response.results });
    });
};
```

You also don't need to specify the query parameters in the backend route.

```
app.get('/people', (req, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: thanks @Tholle. Do the server side queries look like this then: `app.get('/people/?search=$event.target.value', (req, res) => {
    swapi.get('https:swapi.co/api/people/?search=$event.target.value').then((result) => {
       ...
});`

Comment: @ksenia Sorry, I forgot about that. I updated the answer.

Comment: okay, but then how does the `swapi.get` endpoint string look like?

Comment: @ksenia The `swapi.get` looks [like the documentation](https://github.com/salty-pig/swapi-node#readme). Have you tried it now?

Comment: yes, but it gives the first page result only. never the search. My frontend route is using `event.target.value`. My backend route is like so: `app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
    swapi.get('https:swapi.co/api/people/?search='+req.query.search).then((result) => {...`

Comment: @ksenia Try using the same url like the documentation. E.g this one https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=chew

Comment: seem to be doing everything right , passing the right string, insert into the correct link, but the result is a 404

Comment: @ksenia Have you restarted the server?

Comment: thank you, I sure have. I just updated the code to match our troubleshooting efforts. Can you think why it might return a 404?

Comment: if you're curious, the problem was in the proxy. http vs https... Now solved!

Answer (score 0):

fetch call in App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      searchResult: [],
    }
  }

    searchPersonByName = (event) => {
    fetch('/people/?search='+ event.target.value)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        //let searchResult = JSON.parse(responseBody).results;
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ searchResult: response.results });
      })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div className="pageStyle">
        <div className="searchBar">
          <input type="text"
            placeholder="search for a person"
            onChange={this.searchPersonByName}>
          </input>
          {Object.keys(this.state.searchResult).map((item, i) => (
            <li key={i}>
              <span>{this.state.searchResult[item].name}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and backend:

```
//Dependencies
const swapi = require('swapi-node'); 
const express = require('express'); //express server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));

var API_URL = 'http://swapi.co/api/';

//Search people endpoint
//format of the search string:
// https://swapi.co/api/people/?search=
app.get('/people', (req, res) => {
    let query = req.query.search;
    console.log(query);
    swapi.get('http://swapi.co/api/people/?search=' + query).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.results);
        let results = result.results;
        res.send({ results });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

//server listening on specified port
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Listening on port 4000!'))
```